# BufferedReader ReadLine froze the program

Tags: java, bufferedreader

My code is as follows;

When i use BufferedRead readLine() the whole program gets frozen. the problem is that readLine will rnot return the line until it reaches the end of the line. because the server will not send a new line char value it will not close.

So how can i get over this ? Please edit my code;

```
                  while (ok) {
                        BufferedReader re = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                        aString = re.readLine();
                        ...
                    }
```

note: i want to do this programatically, and not go and kill the process that's running it

```
UPDATE

StringBuilder re= new StringBuilder();
                    while ((c = r.read()) >= 0) {
                            re.append( (char)c ) ;  
                    }
                    String result = re.toString();
                    byte[] contentInBytes = result.getBytes();
                    out.write(contentInBytes);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
```

Comment: How much do you want to read? Single bytes? N bytes? Until a timeout?Length prefixed messages?

Comment: What actually you are trying to do. What is the behaviour you are expecting here. Can you please give some more details

Comment: I am trying to download a file. i am receiving 10 bytes at a time. i have updated the latest code above

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the readLine() method of [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).  Use the read() method, which will read individual characters.  You'll have to convert them from ints to characters, but that will get you around not having a newline character to read.

EDIT: Adding 
Assuming "re" is your buffered socket input stream reader...

```
while ((i = re.read()) != -1)
{
   if (i > 0)
   {
      char c = (char) i;
      // Do something with the character
   }
}
```

END EDIT

Additionally if you are concerned about the server not responding, then you may want to place a timeout on the [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29):

```
socket.setSoTimeout(milliseconds);
```

Comment: 1.) Yes, this is what i did. `re` in my one is `BufferedReader`. Is this correct ? 2.) When i did socket.setSoTimeout(500); i got an Exception.ava.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: 1. Yes, `re` should be your `BufferedReader` on your `Socket`.  2. According to the javadocs at the Socket link I posted, if you got a `SocketTimeoutException`, then it looks the Socket had nothing to read for 500 ms when you called "read".

Comment: I have updated my code, and updated the socket time out to 5000. but still the text doesn't get saved to a file. Any clue. help?

Comment: Do you know if the while loop is exited?

Comment: I have added sysout messages, inside the while loop, it doesn't get executed. so the program gets stuck at re.read()